# Are Content Management and Content Strategy the same?

Tags: content, content-management, content-audit, content-strategy

I work as a UX Strategist and always have a content audit performed before I begin any UX project. I've always referred to the planning, arrangement and writing of the content afterwards as Content Strategy. I've notice on this site that there is no content strategy only Content and Content-Management.

I would consider content management as the working with content once the strategy has been written. There are even more than a few posts here that refer to Content Strategy yet no tag. Is content-management and over-arching term that contains content-strategy or are they synonymous or are these two different fields entirely?

Comment: Content management can mean a lot of stuff.  What type of UX project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would assume:

Content Management = the maintenance of existing content in the same content direction. 
(example:  curation of content related to apples)

While

Content Strategy = the development of content direction.
(example: deciding if content related to oranges belong to the apple content)

They are similar but infer different processes.

Comment: That's the way I felt about it. I think the question should have been more about weather or not there should be a tag for content strategy on UX Exchange.